# where I can fins a tutorial on Feurte-catkin 0.4.6?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A tutorial link given on ROS wiki for Feurte-catkin but its not that way good as it is for Groovy-catkin.
Please suggest a good tutorial on Feurte-catkin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66742/where-i-can-fins-a-tutorial-on-feurte-catkin-0.4.6?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's in the [API link on the wiki page](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/), but you have to select Fuerte first.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-07**:
Dear Sir,Thank you. Just trying the same with little extra effort, hope will come. Don't you think this tutorial is not an easy going stuff for a beginner like me, relatively the catkin groovy tutorial is relatively good. However catkin groovy has a lot of changes so that does not works for fuerte.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-07**:
I agree that it is *very* difficult. None of the catkin docs are "beginner", in my opinion. Once you upgrade to more recent ROS versions, I suggest looking at catkin_simple. It's much easier to understand. Consider using rosbuild with Fuerte and waiting until Groovy or Hydro for catkin.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-07**:
Thanking you again. In fact I started Groovy first and started leaning catkin along with implementation of other packages for turtlebot. Unfortunately I had to shift back on Fuerte as Simulator_Gazebo is not available for Groovy, it will be launched with Hydro now. Thanking again for moral booting.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-08**:
Groovy includes `simulator_gazebo-1.7.12`. That version still uses rosbuild, so catkin packages may not depend on it. I expect a catkin version to be released with Hydro.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-08**:
I think I need to try it once more, hope it will come good to me. I wish to give you good news regarding that. Thank you.